# Экспорт БД в Google Drive

Tags: android

В приложении реализовал авторизацию в гугл через Firebase. Но мне нужно еще реализовать экспорт и импорт БД в гугл диск. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализуется? Толковых примеров не нашел в гугл. Полез в документацию, там тоже не все ясно.

Comment: А какая связь между Firebase и Google Drive? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675689/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive

Comment: Все примеры, которые я нашел в интернете реализованы так: Сначала пользователь авторизуется, затем идет работа с диском, но авторизация идет через устаревшие методы, а гугл вроде рекомендует использовать авторизацию через firebase. Так вот хотел узнать, как реализуется экспорт БД в гугл диск, если пользователь уже авторизован в приложении?

Comment: Авторизация через Firebase Authentication и авторизация через Google API, это разные версии. В первом случае вы авторизуетесь на личном сервере, для своих нужд (то-есть это ваш облачный сервер, с возможностями который предоставляет Firebase _и его ценой за использование_). А во втором случае вы авторизуетесь в Google Account (на их сервер и с их правилами). И нет такого понятия как: `устаревшие методы`, если они устарели их уберут или обновят. Вот что вам надо: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library